# Can I trigger an API call?

Tags: zendesk

My boss tells me we're getting Zendesk.  I have no experience with it.  We want to have it notify our system, e.g. via a call to an API which our system could expose.

Can this be done?  Would I instead have to poll the Zendesk API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push notifications in web-applications are also known as "Webhooks". Zendesk does have a Webhook API, documented here:

https://developer.zendesk.com/embeddables/docs/android/handle_push_notifications_wh

and

https://developer.zendesk.com/embeddables/docs/ios/handle_push_notifications_wh

(Ignore the iOS and Android references - it's platform agnostic)

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a combination of a [Trigger](https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/203662246-About-triggers-and-how-they-work) and and [External HTTP Target](https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/203662136-Notifying-external-targets) that sends an HTTP request to your API.

It will basically works like this:

- You configure the external target to direct requests to the url of your API.
- You configure the trigger with:

  - some conditions to look for (such as a ticket being updated with a specific tag), and
  - an action to perform when the conditions are met. In this case the action will be to send an HTTP request (with a JSON body) to the external target mentioned above.
- Then, when the trigger's conditions are met, the trigger will send an HTTP request to your API endpoint.

You can add dynamic data to the JSON body of the request, such as the ticket number, user data, etc.

This article also might be helpful:
https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/204890268

*Note: External Targets are not currently available on the "Essential" Zendesk product, only "Team", "Professional", and "Enterprise."*